# Reprojection of raster

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have two layers. The first one,representing Europe,contains datas in Lambert Azimuthal, therefore I have chosen the EPSG:3035. The second one, representing the world, is in EPSG:4326
Of course for the moment the maps are not matching.
I would like them to match.
I tried Raster>Projections>Warp(reprojections) but I only get exactly the same map set in EPSG:4026 while it is obviously still in EPSG:3035.

I also tried Right click and "Save as" but it did the same, still the same map.

The other solutions I found all concern vector layers.

Comment: You might want to mention the software in which you tried "Raster > Projections > Warp(reprojections)"

Comment: yes sorry, I´m using qgis

Comment: You might need to specify EPSG:3035 as **source** CRS in the warp dialogue. This is an external command, and does not see what you have set on the layer.

Comment: I did it but it does not function, still the same map like is EPSG:3035

Comment: In fact it create a simple rectangle around my map

Comment: Is it the right way to reproject or do I have to try an other method ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution ! In fact the "save as" method function but you have to do exactly this way :
-setting the layer in her projection, that is EPSG:3035
- then right click, "save as" and you precise that you want EPSG:4326 and save it with a new name
- then you open the new layer in a new project where the other layers are in EPSG:4326

In fact, personally I had an other problem hidden : It was not exactly EPSG:3035, I had to create a new projection and change some parameters.